# Automatically turn on Computer from Raspberry Pi (based on user presence in home)

Tags: python, beginner, child-process, raspberry-pi

I know the code is full of useless data and stylistic and analysis errors and I'd really love and appreciate to have a pro's idea about it so I can learn to code (and think) better.

```
import os, time
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
configfilename = "imhome.ini"
scriptpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
configfile = os.path.join(scriptpath, configfilename)
parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read(configfile)
ip_smartphone = parser.get('imhome', 'ip_smartphone')
mac_address_pc = parser.get('imhome', 'mac_address_pc')
hometime_path = parser.get('imhome', 'hometime_path')
in_path = parser.get('imhome', 'in_path')
mp3_path = parser.get('imhome', 'mp3_path')
maximum_time_before_logout = parser.get('imhome', 'maximum_time_before_logout')
if os.path.exists(hometime_path) == False:
        os.system ("touch " + str(hometime_path))
if os.path.exists(in_path) == True:
        os.system ("rm " + str(in_path))
finished = 1
while finished == 1:
    check_presence = os.system ("ping -w 1 " + str (ip_smartphone) + " >/dev/null")
    file_modification_time = (os.path.getmtime(hometime_path))
    file_delta_time = time.time() - file_modification_time
    if check_presence == 0 :
            os.system ("rm " + str(hometime_path))
            change_arrived=("echo " + str(check_presence) + " > hometime")
            os.system (change_arrived)

            if os.path.exists(in_path) == False:
            # You can add any custom commands to execute when home below this row

                os.system ("etherwake " + str(mac_address_pc))            
                os.system ("mpg123 " + str(mp3_path) + " >/dev/null")
                os.system ("touch " + str(in_path))
            # stop adding commands

    elif check_presence == 256 and file_delta_time > int(maximum_time_before_logout):
        if os.path.exists(in_path) == True:
                    os.system ("rm " + str(in_path))
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### 1. Comments on your code

1. You make quite a lot of use here of [`os.system`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system), which runs a command in a subshell. This can be a risky function to use, because the shell can do anything. For example, you write

   ```
   os.system ("rm " + str(hometime_path))
   ```

   but what if `hometime_path` were `-rf *`?

   You're probably safe in this particular program because it's only for your own use and because the strings come from your own configuration file. But it's worth getting into the habit of doing this kind of thing properly, so that in situations which really *are* risky, you'll know what to do.

   In the case of `rm` you can use [`os.unlink`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.unlink):

   ```
   os.unlink(hometime_path)
   ```

   But in the general case, use [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) and use the `--` argument (if necessary) to make sure that the arguments you pass cannot be misinterpreted as options. For example,

   ```
   subprocess.call(['rm', '--', hometime_path])
   ```

   In a case where you want to redirect standard output, like this:

   ```
   os.system ("ping -w 1 " + str (ip_smartphone) + " >/dev/null")
   ```

   you can use the `stdout` keyword argument to `subprocess.call`:

   ```
   subprocess.call(['ping', '-w', '1', '--', ip_smartphone],
                   stdout = open('/dev/null', 'w'))
   ```
2. Most of your calls to `str` are unnecessary: these configuration parameters ought to be strings already. (If they are not, I think it you'd prefer to get an exception so that you could fix the problem, rather than silently coercing the incorrect value to a string.)
3. You don't need to compare booleans explicitly to `True` and `False`. So instead of:

   ```
   if os.path.exists(in_path) == True:
   ```

   just write:

   ```
   if os.path.exists(in_path):
   ```

   and instead of:

   ```
   if os.path.exists(hometime_path) == False:
   ```

   just write:

   ```
   if not os.path.exists(hometime_path):
   ```
4. In this code you remove a file only if it exists:

   ```
   if os.path.exists(in_path) == True:
       os.system ("rm " + str(in_path))
   ```

   But the `rm` command already has a option for this, so you could write instead:

   ```
   subprocess.call(['rm', '-f', '--', in_path])
   ```

   Or do it in pure Python:

   ```
   try:
       os.unlink(in_path)
   except OSError: # No such file or directory
       pass
   ```

   (This is an example of how it is often better to ask for forgiveness than permission.)
5. Assuming that `" > hometime"` is a mistake for `" > " + hometime_path` (as suggested in another answer), then in this bit of code:

   ```
   os.system ("rm " + str(hometime_path))
   change_arrived=("echo " + str(check_presence) + " > hometime")
   os.system (change_arrived)
   ```

   you remove a file and then overwrite it with the value of `check_presence`. There's no need to remove the file first: the second command will overwrite it if it exists.

   And in any case this is easy to do in pure Python:

   ```
   with open(hometime_path, 'w') as f:
       f.write('{}\n'.format(check_presence))
   ```
6. You use the modification time of the file `hometime_path` to remember the last time that your `ping` command succeeded. Why not remember this time in a variable in Python and avoid having to create and delete and examine this file?
7. You use the existence of the file `in_path` to remember whether your smartphone is connected. Why not remember this fact in a variable in Python and avoid having to create and delete and examine this file?

#### 2. Rewrite

Making the above improvements results in something like this (but this is untested, so beware):

```
import os, subprocess, time
from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

configfilename = "imhome.ini"
scriptpath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
configfile = os.path.join(scriptpath, configfilename)
parser = SafeConfigParser()
parser.read(configfile)
ip_smartphone = parser.get('imhome', 'ip_smartphone')
mac_address_pc = parser.get('imhome', 'mac_address_pc')
mp3_path = parser.get('imhome', 'mp3_path')
timeout = timedelta(seconds = int(parser.get('imhome', 'maximum_time_before_logout')))

devnull = open('/dev/null', 'wb')
connected = False
disconnect_time = None

while True:
    ping = subprocess.call(['ping', '-w', '1', '--', ip_smartphone],
                           stdout = devnull)
    if ping == 0:
        disconnect_time = datetime.now() + timeout
        if not connected:
            connected = True
            subprocess.call(['etherwake', mac_address_pc])
            subprocess.call(['mpg123', mp3_path], stdout = devnull)
    elif ping == 256 and connected and datetime.now() > disconnect_time:
        connected = False
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This is seriously great fuel for my brain! I am VERY thankful also for the time you took to explain and incredibly rewrite the code! I'll hide it in my drawer and try to write it on my own to check how I do compared to you.
If you happen to be in central Italy you have a dinner paid! :D

Comment: I'm finally back from my holidays and I am trying to understand better your work... I can't get how you handle time...
If I print the variables to understand what is going on I still can't get it.
The main problem is timeout.
in timeout you get the number of seconds defined in the config file, right?
And then you use this to calculate disconnect_time adding this very moment to maximum time before logout?
Why?
Maybe it's just a mistake (you told me it wasn't checked) but I am a newbie so... :)

Comment: The idea is that `disconnect_time` is the clock time at which the program will consider the smartphone to be disconnected if it hasn't received any more ping responses by then. Each time a ping response is received, we update `diconnect_time` to a be a bit further in the future. But if we don't receive any ping responses, we leave it unchanged, until eventually `datetime.now() > disconnect_time`. (This is a standard idiom for timeout processing.)

Comment: Mmmh ok...

But why to you sum it with timeout (which is the value included in my config file)?

Comment: Suppose that your config file has timeout = 15 seconds. Then each time we receive a ping response, we set `disconnect_time = datetime.now() + timeout`. That is, `disconnect_time` now represents a time 15 seconds in the future. If we haven't received any more ping responses by then, we'll consider the smartphone to be disconnected.

Comment: I am trying to debug it to understand better (putting print variables to understand what is going on) and it seems that it gets to execute commands just a single time. It never gets in connected = False again...

Comment: If you're not getting to the line `connected = False`, that means that one of the previous conditions is not true. That is, either `ping` is not 256, or `connected` is false, or `datetime.now()` is before `disconnect_time`. Which is these is the case? (It could be that `ping == 256` is the wrong way to test for ping failure, for example. I just copied that from your original script. On my operating system, `ping` exits with status 2 if it fails to get a response from the host.)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7285/discussion-between-pitto-and-gareth-rees)

Comment: Copy and paste is your enemy!

All the indentation was blown away: it works perfectly and I've understood it.

Thanks a lot, again :)

Answer (score 6):

Neat idea with that script. It looks good; not bad for the first program.  Just a few comments:

1. I would improve some variable names: `file_modification_time` -> `phone_last_seen_time`, `file_delta_time` -> `phone_unseen_duration`.  When I was reading the program it took me some time to figure out their purpose.
2. Use `while True:` instead of `while finished == 1:` so it is immediately clear that it is an infinite loop.
3. In the line `change_arrived=("echo " + str(check_presence) + " > hometime")` you probably want `str(hometime_path)` instead of `"hometime"`.
4. It would be also good to describe purpose of some variables in comments.  Mainly `hometime_path` and `in_path`.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a `time.sleep(1)` call at the end of the loop.  Without that I had to kill the program from the shell to stop it, as it was not responding to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.